# Remap key in mobaxterm

Tags: linux, terminal, mobaxterm, control-characters

Currently <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> returns `^H` in my linux console.
How to remap this to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd>?

I use the newest version of MobaXterm "Personal Edition 8.6".

Answer (score 1):

Your tty settings are probably set to send delete char ^? for erase rather than backspace ^H character

type `stty` in the terminal to see what the *erase* is set to

try doing this in the shell to set it to [backspace] key.

```
stty erase ^H
```

to get the ^H character you need to use [ctrl] + [v] and then [backspace] keys. If that makes works you can add that to your .profile or .bashrc file

or you can make moba xterm send ^? when you type [backspace] by going to settings and on the terminal tab uncheck the option backspace sends ^H